# Is there a method to determine if a document is a file of text sentences?

Tags: java, clojure, nlp, stanford-nlp, statistics

I'm processing hundreds of thousands of files. Potentially millions later on down the road. A bad file will contain a text version of an excel spreadsheet or other text that isn't binary but also isn't sentences. Such files cause CoreNLP to blow up (technically, these files take a long time to process such as 15 seconds per kilobyte of text.) I'd love to detect these files and discard them in sub-second time.

What I am considering is taking a few thousand files at random, examining the first, say, 200 characters and looking for the distribution of characters to determine what is legic and what is an outlier. Example, if there are no punctuation marks or too many of them. Does this seem like a good approach? Is there a better one that has been proven? I think, for sure, this will work well enough, possibly throwing out potentially good files but rarely.

Another idea is to simply run with annotators tokenize and ssplit and do word and sentence count. That seems to do a good job as well and returns quickly. I can think of cases where this might fail as well, possibly.

Comment: I'd worry less about throwing out potentially good files than about not throwing out potentially bad files. You should probably also check for line and word length. Just for curiosities sake, why are there "bad" files in the system to begin with? (I think your approach should work, but really you should probably just implement it and try to get it to fail). I'm not too sure whether or not this is a good question for SO though.

Comment: What about just reading the last few bytes of the files? I assume there is some special formatting that is specific to excel files which has to do with their encoding.

Comment: Maybe easier to find a signature of the "text version of an excel spreadsheet"?  There must be some file header or footer data in there?

Comment: "Bad files" end up in the stream because they are what have been found in place. In doing general forensics the issue comes up that even in email a message can contain lots of text but none of it useful for parsing. Some of it has been converted to text using various other software. I won't have control over it so I have to do a check to see if it is at least something that passes a "sniff test".

Comment: So this got closed for being "too broad" but I am unsure what that even means? This is a particular class of problem. A processing pipeline, that works well for a certain class of input, can fail if a hard to detect class of input is introduced. I fail to see how seeking an approach to solve this class of problem is "too broad"? it certainly isn't off topic. I find the editing here at Stack Exchange often quite arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of processing pipeline is always in a state of continuous improvement. To kick off that process, the first thing I would build is an instrument around the timing behavior of CoreNLP. If CoreNLP is taking too long, kick out the offending file into a separate queue. If this isn't good enough, you can write recognizers for the most common things in the takes-too-long queue and divert them before they hit CoreNLP. The main advantage of this approach is that it works with inputs that you don't expect in advance.

Comment: That is a good idea even if I stick with my plan. A file that gets past my filter(s) could still attempt to thrash heap and processing time.

Comment: Oh, I agree with the assumption in your original post that you'll need to recognize "bad text" in your processing pipeline. What I'm hesitant to do is to suggest ways of recognizing bad text in advance of actually seeing it. Hence my suggestion to create a piece of the pipeline that gives you a collection of unambiguously bad text. Then, when you write a recognizer, you have two collections of text, one good and one bad, and you can test that the candidate recognizer matches on _some_ of the bad text and _none_ of the good text (or at least minuscule amounts).

Comment: As it turns out in practice over the last few months the use of a Bayesian classifier using the Gaussian features of byte distribution works remarkably well. Looking at the possible distribution of all bytes, adding in confidence for the percentage of times the feature was seen in the training set, a positive and negative classifier produces excellent results. It can tell the difference quite easily. While it helps to remove non-text files that are obvious like image files the real problem were the non-semantically structured text files and those do stand out from the files I want to process.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main approaches to this kind of problem.

The first is to take the approach you are considering in which you examine the contents of the file and decide whether it is acceptable text or not based on a statistical analysis of the data in the file.

The second approach is to use some kind of meta tag such as a file extension to at least eliminate those files that are pretty certainly to be a problem (.pdf, .jpg, etc.).

I would suggest a mixture of the two approaches so as to cut down on the amount of processing.

You might consider a pipeline approach in which you have a sequence of tests.  The first test filters out files based on meta data such as the file extension, the second step then does a preliminary statistical check on the first few bytes of the file to filter out obvious problem files, a third step does a more involved statistical analysis of the text, and the fourth handles the CoreNLP rejection step.

You do not say where the files originate nor if there are any language considerations (English versus French versus Simplified Chinese text).  For instance are the acceptable text files using UTF-8, UTF-16, or some other encoding for the text?

Also is it possible for the CoreNLP application to be more graceful about detecting and rejecting incompatible text files?

Comment: I'll have no idea where the original source of the input is. 95% will be text filtered from unstructured text. The "problem children" will be the results of people putting into various streams things they should not. Much like in real life. So, the original text might come from email, a PDF, etc. This is filtered as best as possible already. Some of it may be a result of a badly handled file attachment such as a spreadsheet. Some will simply be things like PDF product sheets - lots of text but none of it is really properly analyzed with CoreNLP. I like your sequence of filters idea!

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just train a Naive Bayes Classifier to recognize the bad files? For features use things like (binned) percentage of punctuation, percentage of numerical characters, and average sentence length.

Comment: Another thing I found is that some messages have good text and bad text. For example an email contained a paragraph of good text and then THOUSANDS of lines listing attachments. 6000+ concepts were pulled from the document. That is the most pathological case. Its probably best solved with pre-processing and looking for specific patterns. It would be nice to have something smarter though and a Naïve Bayes Classifier would be just that.

Answer (score -1):

Peter,

You are clearly dealing with files for ediscovery.  Anything and everything is possible, and as you know, anything kicked out must be logged as an exception.  I've faced this, and have heard the same from other analytics processors.

Some of the solutions above, pre-process and in-line can help.  In some ediscovery solutions it may be feasible to dump text into a field in SQL and truncate, or otherwise truncate, and still get what you need.  In other apps, anything to do with semantic clustering, or predictive coding, it may be better to use pre-filters using metadata (e.g. file type), document type classification libraries, and entity extraction based upon prior examples, current sampling or your best guess as to the nature of "bad file" contents.

Good luck.

Comment: I've found that classifiers can easily detect a lack of semantic structure in a target text file. Of all the solutions I've tried that one has the greatest success rate. The training of the classifier is so easy it is possible to have the system automate it, though I think a curated approach will produce better results because you can create multiple classifiers based upon visual inspection of what the file contains. It doesn't take many files to produce a working classifier which is another benefit.